# localStorage.setItem for AJAX api call not defined until after function runs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to figure out why localStorage.setItem in my function is not running until the end.

jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 OPTIONS http://169.254.10.10:8080/api/v0/sessions/undefined/operations/start 404 (Not Found)

The console.log id number comes last, after trying the second api call which would make sense based on my error. I know it's hard to help test and validate but if anyone could help that would be great.

```
0: {apiGatewayVersion: "1.24", activeTime: "0", id: 75 }
1: {apiGatewayVersion: "1.24", activeTime: "0", id: 76 }
2: {apiGatewayVersion: "1.24", activeTime: "0", id: 77 }
3: {apiGatewayVersion: "1.24", activeTime: "0", id: 78 }
length: 4


function startSession() {
    var _url = "http://169.254.10.10:8080/api/v0/sessions"
    $.ajax({
        "url": _url,
        "method": "GET",
        "timeout": 0,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            var max = 0;
                for (var property in response) {
                max = (max < parseFloat(property)) ? parseFloat(property) : max;
                }
            var data = JSON.stringify(response[max]);
            var parse = JSON.parse(data);
            var id = parse.id;
            localStorage.setItem('id', id);
        console.log(localStorage.id);
});
    var _url2 = "http://169.254.10.10:8080/api/v0/sessions" + localStorage.id + "/operations/start"
    $.ajax({
        "url": _url2,
        "method": "POST",
        "timeout": 0,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
});
    alert("Session Starting, Please wait...")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot directly access local storage item as `localStorage.id`

[Read manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and fix Your code:

```
var _url2 = "http://169.254.10.10:8080/api/v0/sessions/" + localStorage.getItem('id') + "/operations/start"
```

since You're using behaviour of a Promise where race condition may happen, make sure You start operations after successful getting session.

where I don't see logical reason of using local storage during operation start:

```
function startSession() {
    var _url = "http://169.254.10.10:8080/api/v0/sessions"
    var request = $.ajax({
        "url": _url,
        "method": "GET",
        "timeout": 0,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
    });
    request.then(function (response) {
      /*
      [
        {apiGatewayVersion: "1.24", activeTime: "0", id: 75 },
        {apiGatewayVersion: "1.24", activeTime: "0", id: 76 },
        {apiGatewayVersion: "1.24", activeTime: "0", id: 77 },
        {apiGatewayVersion: "1.24", activeTime: "0", id: 78 }
      ]
      */
      // Your session list is sorted by id order, 
      // and last session is last object in array
      // it's enough to get last object from response array
      var lastSession = (Array.isArray(response) && response.length)
                        ? response[response.length-1]
                        : {id: 0};
      localStorage.setItem('id', lastSession.id);

      var _url2 = "http://169.254.10.10:8080/api/v0/sessions/" + localStorage.getItem('id') + "/operations/start";
      // or simply:
      // var _url2 = "http://169.254.10.10:8080/api/v0/sessions/" + lastSession.id + "/operations/start";
      $.ajax({
        "url": _url2,
        "method": "POST",
        "timeout": 0,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
      }).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      });

      alert("Session Starting, Please wait...")
    });
}
```

P.S. In case if response is object instead of array:

```
      /*
      {
       0: {apiGatewayVersion: "1.24", activeTime: "0", id: 75 },
       1: {apiGatewayVersion: "1.24", activeTime: "0", id: 76 },
       2: {apiGatewayVersion: "1.24", activeTime: "0", id: 77 },
       3: {apiGatewayVersion: "1.24", activeTime: "0", id: 78 }
      }
      */
      response = Object.values(response); // add this
      var lastSession = (Array.isArray(response) && response.length)
                        ? response[response.length-1]
                        : {id: 0};
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I was using localStorage in order to have the session id persist until the user logs out, where upon a delete operation is sent to the api gateway. looks like I could alternatively use sessionstorage. we probably won't have too many simultaneous users so maybe I wouldn't need to use either option

Comment: @PA_Commons in any case I gave answer with alternative without localstorage (see comments in code). But yes, session management should not be made on clientside. Only thing Clientside should keep is session id (access token) for internal authorization. Otherwise You’re giving users ability to manually call session operation start of different user (maybe not).